# Vue Components with data and methods

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm taking an online course which corrects code using a bot. In this course I'm learnig HTML, JS and Vue.JS.

The assignemnt is to create a component, `greet` that produces `<div>Welcome, Alice!</div>` when it's called using `<greet></greet>` The assignment also wants me to use `data` and `methods` to make it so it says `Welcome, Bob` instead when you click om the `div` element in the component. It tells me to use the `data` and `methods` key in the component.

This is my code so far, but I'm stuck.
HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="app"><greet></greet>
    </div>
</body>
```

Vue code:

```
Vue.component('greet', {
  data() {
    return {   
    }
  },
  template: '<div>Welcome</div>'
})

new Vue({ el: '#app' })
```

How do I make it so it says Welcome, Alice! and when pressed, it says Welcome, Bob! ?
The bot gives me an output of

```
file.js
    ✓ exists
    ✓ is valid JavaScript
    1) renders the correct markup when no clicks are made
    2) renders the correct markup when one click is made
```

Answer (score 0):

In your data property, define a variable that will hold access to the `name` so to speak. In this case, we'll initialize it with a value of `Alice`:

```
data () {
  return {
    name: 'Alice'
  }
}
```

We can add a click method now and bind it to our `div` element so that it will swap the name:

```
methods: {
  swap () {
    this.name = 'Bob'
  }

}
```

Finally, we need to modify our `template` to receive a `click handler` and use dynamic bindings to display our `name` property from our `data` object:

```
template: `<div @click="swap">Welcome, <span v-text="name"></span></div>`
```

Note that in the above illustration the `v-text` is a [directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html) and we have bound the value of our `name` property to it, which we modify through the `@click` handler we assigned to the `swap` function.

Comment: The bout gave me an output of.   file.js
    ✓ exists
    ✓ is valid JavaScript
    1) renders the correct markup when no clicks are made
    2) renders the correct markup when one click is made

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event `@click` on the div, with that you bind the click event to a specific method in this case I create `toggleName()`

```
  Vue.component('greet', {
      data() {
        return {
         name: 'Alice'
        }
      },
      methods: {
        toggleName() {
          this.name = this.name == 'Alice' ? 'Bob' : 'Alice';
        }
      },
      template: '<div @click="toggleName">Welcome {{ name }}</div>'
    })
```

Then we create a method that accesses to the property defined in `data` in this case is `name` When we use the reserved word `this` we access to our instance and from there w can access the property `name`. Then we create a toggle for the name.

In order to access the variable in our template we need to use the special curly braces
`{{ name }}` this time the `this` is not needed.

Comment: The bot gave me an output of: ` + actual - expected

+ '<greet></greet>'
- '<div>Välkommen, Alice!</div>'
      + expected - actual

      -<greet></greet>
      +<div>Välkommen, Alice!</div> `

Comment: Didn't get that last, of course, you should make some modifications so that it matches what you expect.